# Sort list of tuple in descending order with category alternating condition

Tags: scala, sorting

Given a list of tuples:

```
val mylist = List(('orange', 0.9, 1), ('apple', 0.8, 1), ('mellon', 0.7, 1), 
                  ('car', 0.5, 2), ('truck', 0.5, 2),
                  ('tablet', 0.3, 3))
```

I would like to sort them in descending order with respect to the second element of the tuple. However, I would like to pick them by category, one at a time (third element) alternatively. The output should be the following list:

```
('orange', 0.9, 1)
('car', 0.5, 2)
('tablet', 0.3, 3)
('apple', 0.8, 1) 
('truck', 0.5, 2)
('mellon', 0.7, 1)
```

What would be the functional way of doing it in Scala?

Comment: This isn't valid Scala code. `'` is used to define `Character` literals, not `String`s.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
mylist.groupBy(_._3) // group by category
      .toList
      .sortBy(_._1)  // sort by asc category
      .map(_._2.sortBy(-_._2)) // drop the category key + sort each group by desc rank
      .flatMap(_.zipWithIndex) 
      .sortBy(_._2) // sort by index (stable sort)
      .map(_._1)    // drop the index

> res: List[(String, Double, Int)] = List((orange,0.9,1), (car,0.5,2), (tablet,0.3,3), (apple,0.8,1), (truck,0.5,2), (mellon,0.7,1))
```

Comment: it fails with the following:
 `val a = List((312, 0.1, 13), (222, 0.9, 13), (112, 0.5, 13), (221, 0.1, 4), (3211, 0.2 ,4), (23231, 0.1, 15), (4121312, 0.3, 1))`

`res1: List[(Int, Double, Int)] = List((4121312,0.3,1), (3211,0.2,4), (222,0.9,13), (23231,0.1,15), (221,0.1,4), (112,0.5,13), (312,0.1,13))`

as you can see the first tuple should be of type `13`